# Validating data + writing line by line with BufferedWriter from scanner input

Tags: java

My brief is to write bits of data about employees (validate the age as an integer, salary as double.) Once validated, the info must be written to a file line by line. There must be 3 employee records.

My current code, as seen below, accepts 12 lines of data and places them line by line into the file. What I'm unsure about is how to validate the input. I need name and title simply as anything, and then I need age as integer and salary as double.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner employeeData = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the employee name, title, age and salary. Press enter after each piece of information: ");
    try {
        File file = new File("employee.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            bw.write(employeeData.next() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        bw.close();
    }catch (IOException e1) {
        System.err.println("The file doesn't exist.");
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e2) {
        System.err.println("Incorrect data type. Name and job title can be string, age whole number and Salary must be double (with decimals).");
    }


    finally{

        System.out.println("Done.");

    }
    employeeData.close();
}
```

}

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Does it raise an error, or do you encounter an unexpected behavior (if so, what is it?) ?

Comment: As a side note, it's considered conventnion to use `i`,`j`,`k`, etc for nested looping and other iterators

Comment: As another side note, it's wasteful to recreate the `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter` each iteration since you're writing to the same target.

Comment: @Aaron, it doesn't raise an error no. What's happening is that it is overwriting a single line each loop (instead of writing to a new line each time.) It's also not validating the age and salary but that's because I'm still researching on how to do that. So the file simply has one line all the time, and ignores the other 11 lines of data.

Comment: @theKunz Thanks, will update and also thanks to Aaron again.

Comment: I've updated the code above. The suggestions posted in the comments have fixed one issue. It now writes 4 lines of data (but I need this to happen 3 times)

Comment: I haven't used `FileWriter` in a while but I can see there's a `FileWriter(String path, boolean append)` constructor. My guess is that when using `FileWriter(String path)` `append` defaults to false, making you overwrite the file each time. Follow my advice not to recreate the `FileWriter` at each iteration and you should be sorted out.

Comment: Create the FileWriter outside of the loops :) You're still creating it 3 times, overwriting the file each time.

Comment: TBH this is something you should have guessed yourself. "Before I had only one line, now that I've created the FileWriter one level higher it writes 4 lines. How could I reach 12 ? Could I reproduce the same thing, is there any higher level?" Don't rely too much on StackOverflow or you won't learn !

Comment: @Aaron I can still learn mistakes here! I'm nearly brand new at it so it'll take time. I've updated my question - what I really need now is validation.

Comment: While your current code looks ok, I think the fact you merged your two loops will be problematic once you tackle the validation problem : right now you're writing 12 lines and their content don't matter, but when validating you'll have to check the first line is a string, the second a double, etc. So I'd consider decomposing your loop in two nested loops as you had before (for now, just `for(...) { for(...) { bw.write(...) } }` is enough).

Comment: Also I see you're using `Scanner.next()`, which is inconsistent with the text you're displaying to the user : it will only consume a word rather than a whole line.

Comment: I see but bw.write(employeeData.nextDouble()); returns an error, "the method(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments (double)